# How to find Free music (tracks) on Google Play?

Tags: google-play-music

Just re-discovered Google Play after they opened their new Music All Access offer in EU, and saw this on their front page:
"Shop for millions of songs from your favorite artists, including hundreds of free tracks from the biggest names in Rock, Pop, Hip-Hop, and more."

So I wonder how to find the free tracks available?

There is the "Deal of the day" (every day a new track for free):
http://play.google.com/store/music/collection/deal_of_the_day

Also found another URL in several blogs/posts, entitled "GET THE HOTTEST SONGS, FREE ON GOOGLE PLAY!"
http://play.google.com/store/music/collection/series_overview_theme_2011_10_29
But it's empty now.

Any ideas?

PS: there is (was) a blog called "Magnifier" on Blogspot that somehow promoted such tracks, but it's not been updated since late December 2012, as they said they have been absorbed by Google Play.

Answer (score 3):

If you scroll down a bit at the [Google Play (Music) Store](https://play.google.com/store/music), you'll see a big banner for free music.

Here's what it looks like for me today:

[image: Google Play Free Music]

Click the banner and you'll get a list of available songs. I see about a dozen. They change fairly regularly.

Below the banner is also the "Free song of the day".

I am in the U.S. If you are in another country this may not be the same for you.

Comment: Mmh... seems like there's some restriction in there because I can't see it. You're located in the US, are you? Can you provide the link to this "Free Music" section? Thanks.

Comment: @maxxyme: I'm in the US, yes. Here's the current link to the antenna sampler: https://play.google.com/store/music/collection/series_overview_antenna_201029e_ant_august_antenna

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I get this message: "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: So clearly we, French, but widely (I suppose) non-US people, are out of this "Free music" offer. Kinda frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

I use MumbleBee's blog to locate free music offered on Google Play. Sometimes, I'm not able to visit the Google Play music store every day so this blog catches me up on missed (free) tunes with a direct link to the song.

Of course, some of the tunes are free for a limited time. So I wouldn't wait too long before checking back.

URL: http://mumblebeeinc.com/tag/google-play-free-song-of-the-day/

Comment: Thank you for this blog link. As you said, it seems the tunes are free for a limited time only, I was unable to locate any free one as of now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best search term for finding free music in Google play.

free songs

You can add some additional tags to this like:

-bible
-christmas